# Best practices for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing a new application using the Entity Framework.

Where would the EF lie?  My current thinking is to isolate it in a DataAccess assembly that exposes a number of repositories (that essentially wrap EF).

I would then create my own Domain objects and pass them to the repository that maps them to an EntityFramework Entity (which I treat as a DAO).

The problem with this approach is the amount of mapping I would need to do, even for a smaller domain model.

I also like the `Repository.GetAll(Func<TDomainObj, bool> filter)` approach to retrieve a filtered number of items, however I would need to convert the function to take a DAO instead:

`Func<**TDomainObj**, bool> filter` --->

```
Func<**TEntityFrameworkObj**, bool> filter
```

Not sure how I could do that?  If I simply allowed `Func<TEntityFrameworkObj, bool>` on the repository, the caller would have to know about `System.Data.Objects`.

I'm starting to think I should just couple the app to EF and use their `System.Data.Objects` as my model....

Look forward to your suggestions/comments,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We encapsulate EF behind a service layer. The service layer exposes DTO objects. We map the EF objects to DTO objects in code.

In some cases we do a get by template, which is similar to what you are doing. Where we send in a object, for example a customer and get back all customers that look like the one we sent in.

Answer (score 2):

Julie Lerman [has a free, online presentation on EF tips and tricks tomorrow](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-tips-amp-tricks-webcast-this-thursday/).

I will be presenting "*How to Think Like the Entity Framework (and why you might want to bother doing so in the first place)*" at the [free, online CodeRage conference in September](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/coderage/sessions#3WednesdaySeptember). The presentation will be available for download shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I watched Julies presentation :)  I will keep an eye open for yours... very helpful with all this :)